# StackOverflow Questions Remap (new nav)

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, topbar

Here's a quick userscript for Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey that lets you remap the Questions button in the new navbar (new as of 2017-02-14) to a different link.

For example, if you like to read [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) and [swift](/questions/tagged/swift), you could map the Questions link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift%20ios?mode=all and go directly to that from the new navbar.

It's hosted on Github: https://github.com/snoopy369/SOQuestionsRemap  and licensed with the [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) license.